# What's the biohazard symbol on the player info card mean?

Tags: gun-monkeys

When in the multiplayer lobby, if you hover over another player or yourself you see a pop-up info card showing their current perk set, games played and winning percentage.

Some of these cards also have a biohazard symbol in the top-right:

[image: player pop-up with biohazard symbol]

And some of them don't:

[image: player pop-up without biohazard symbol]

I'm mildly curious as to what the symbol means?